# Multiple Angular2 routers in one app (RC5)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

In my angular2 application, I have a global router, which navigates through a number of functions, e.g. home and tutorial. Now in my tutorial component, I want to set up another router to navigate through the different steps.

So globally, here are my files:

```
//main.ts:
// The browser platform with a compiler
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

// The app module
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

// Compile and launch the module
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

app.routes.ts:

```
import { homeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { tutorialComponent } from './tutorial/tutorial.component';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: homeComponent },
  { path: 'tutorial', component: tutorialComponent }
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

and `app.component.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { sidebarComponent } from './sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { navbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { homeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { tutorialComponent } from './tutorial/tutorial.component';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <sidebar></sidebar>
  <navbar></navbar>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
  directives: [sidebarComponent, navbarComponent, homeComponent, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  precompile: [homeComponent, tutorialComponent]
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

Now in my tutorial component, I would like it to look like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tutorial',
  template: `
           <a routerLink="/chapter/1" routerLinkActive="active">Chapter 1</a>
           <a routerLink="/chapter/2" routerLinkActive="active">Chaoter 2</a>
           <router-outlet><router-outlet>,
  directives: [chapterComponent, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class tutorialComponent {
    public chapters = _chapters;
    clickedItem: number = 0;
 }
```

So I am not quite sure how to approach this. Do I need to re-bootstrap, where do I define the routes for my "sub-router"? Maybe I reference this in my original bootstrap, in which case how to I discern between the two routers. I would like this to really act as a subrouter, so when I navigate to the tutorial component currently, my address is `myDomain.com/tutorial`, I would then like to invoke my subrouter and get to routes like `myDomain.coom/tutorial/chapter/1`
.
The docs state that only one router can be used per template which suggests what I want to do is possible? But there is no mention of what to do for the second one.

Comment: Change the order of the routes in app.routes.ts, the empty one at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I maybe a little late to the party, but I found this plunker to be more than helpful when it comes to `RC5`:

https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/router/ts/plnkr.html

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I need to create a child "tutorial" module with its own child routes and then register it into my `app.module.ts` as described with the crisis center in the [Official](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) docs.